# how to back up flutter source code from git?

Tags: android, git, flutter, visual-studio-code, backup

i have a huge issue, i was working on my flutter app and my laptop suddenly burned. Hopefully i was able to extract my data and put it on an external hard drive.
With a new computer i try to find my application and use it but in the folder of my application i find new files like: vsc.xml,
runConfigurations.xml, modules.xml. But all my folders: lib, pubspec.yaml disappeared as you can see in the picture.
I used visual studio code and git on my old computer. I am totally new with git and flutter and this why i would like to know
how is it possible to get back all my code? I’m desperate, it’s months of work... if your have a  solution i will be very glad to hear it.

If it's not possible to get back my code, i have the last version of my app on my phone is it possible to extract the code source from my phone ??

Thank you for your help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4XRC.png)

PS: Sorry for my frenchglish

Comment: Did you push the code to the git repository? By push I mean create a commit and push it on any branch

Comment: Did you back up your project on GitHub or any other Git providers? If yes, you can retrieve your project there.

Comment: As i said i'm totaly new with git but i push my code for the first time . i create a secondary branch but when i go to github i'm not able to see this new branch.

Comment: The only thing i can  see on github is my first commit ..